# Mixed content IE 8 vs IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, https

Is there a difference between in the way IE8 handles mixed cotent than IE9 ? I am looking at a leagacy DotNetNuke https site. When I go the https site using IE 8 I get the mixed cotent warning message, however when I browse the https site using IE9 I dont get the mixed content warning popup. The Display mixed content setting in both the browsers has been set to Prompt. I always see the prompt after the whole page is loaded and irrespective of whether I select Yes or No in the mixed content warning, I see the same content on the page.

Does anyone know why I see different behaviours in IE8 and IE9? Does any other browser setting influence whether the user is shown the mixed content warning ?

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour in respect to mixed content should be the same.  What's not the same, however, is the document mode that the page gets loaded in.  Can you confirm that the the content that triggers the mixed mode warning actually gets loaded over HTTP in IE9 mode?  Note that for your scenario, the document modes might be different for any nested documents as well (i.e.: iframes).

You should be able to check this stuff through dev tool bar.